# unreachable statement error at for loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class dectobin
{
public static void main(String agrs[])
{
int i,a1;
int val[]=new int[20];
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a decimal number");
a1=sc.nextInt();
while(true)
{
i=0;
val[i]=a1%2;
a1=a1/2;
i++;
}

for(i=val.length;i>=0;i--)
{
System.out.println(+val[i]);
}
}    
}
```

im not able to excute my code as i am getting an error at for loop as unreachable statement and im not getting any output because of it.

Comment: Indent your code properly -- this may just give you the answer

Comment: Never mind -- `while (true)` -- when will that loop ever end? Don't just type code -- try to understand it.

Comment: Please indent your code to increase readability. So then others can understand your code easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop runs forever

```
while(true)
{
i=0;
val[i]=a1%2;
a1=a1/2;
i++;
}
```

That's why for loop is unreachable. Try to have some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`For` loop is unreachable as well as all lines below your `while(true)` loop since `while(true)` loop is infinite. That means program won't ever go outside `while` loop and continue execution of other lines

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a while(true) condition which goes on forever. It looks like you don't need a while loop and can replace it with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get outside of while loop. Make an exit condition for it. Anyway it is bad practice to use while loops with no condition in the head.
If you cannot write an entry-point condition then try do-while loop
E.g.

```
do {
//...
}
while(i < 10);
```